# Find average of rows

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to find the average of a set of results that come from a select:

I have already found the average of a row of results but I need to then find the average of averages but im struggling to count the rows and do tha math.

here is my PHP:

```
<?php
$dansql2 = "SELECT team_members.team_id, team_members.member_id, members.member_id, 
                    members.firstName, members.lastName, members.score_1, members.score_2, 
                    members.score_3, members.score_4, members.score_5, members.score_6, 
                    members.score_7, members.score_8
            FROM team_members 
                JOIN members
                    ON team_members.member_id = members.member_id
            WHERE members.dashboard_id = $dashboard_id 
              AND team_members.team_id = $teamSelect
            ORDER BY members.firstName ASC";


$danresult = $conn->query($dansql2);?>
<?php      
if ($danresult->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $danresult->fetch_assoc()) {

        $score1 = $row["score_1"];
        $score2 = $row["score_2"];
        $score3 = $row["score_3"];
        $score4 = $row["score_4"];
        $score5 = $row["score_5"];
        $score6 = $row["score_6"];
        $score7 = $row["score_7"];
        $score8 = $row["score_8"];

        $sum = $score1 + $score2 + $score3 + $score4 + $score5 + $score6 + $score7 + $score8;
        $totalAverage = $sum / 8;

        echo $totalAverage; 
    }
}
?>
```

so what I need to find the total average of is from the $totalAverage variable. That prints out the average of each of the rows scores but I need to tall up the $totalAverage

Comment: Your database design looks bad. You could just have made a `team_members_score` table and related it to a `team_members` row as many times as you wanted instead of having `score_n`. That way the average would have been a simple aggregate function instead of this whole ordeal.

Comment: @Michael all done sorry about that.

Comment: Maybe look at [MySQL AVG()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_avg)

Comment: @Michael 'Just replace them with echo `$totalAverage`' I have just updated this now does that make it clearer?

Comment: Come on thats got to be generating ERRORS. This line `$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);` before even issuing the query and using a NON EXISTING variable `$result` ?????????

Comment: @RiggsFolly sorry I was testing something Im doing a count above all of this codeblock. Ill remove it.

Comment: What do you mean by average or averages

Comment: Im looking for the mean of the values. So where I have the variable $totalAverage its an output of averages of the scores. I am looking to find the mean of the all $totalAverage

Comment: So one example would be there could be a set or count of 7 `$totalAverage` and I need to first of all get the sum of all those and then divide them by the count of 7 in this case but the count could be different everytime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you means something like this

```
<?php
$dansql2 = "SELECT team_members.team_id, team_members.member_id, members.member_id, 
                    members.firstName, members.lastName, 
                    members.score_1, members.score_2, 
                    members.score_3, members.score_4, 
                    members.score_5, members.score_6, 
                    members.score_7, members.score_8,
                    (members.score_1 + members.score_2 +
                    members.score_3 + members.score_4 + 
                    members.score_5 + members.score_6 +
                    members.score_7 + members.score_8 ) / 8 as membersAvg
            FROM team_members 
                JOIN members
                    ON team_members.member_id = members.member_id
            WHERE members.dashboard_id = $dashboard_id 
              AND team_members.team_id = $teamSelect
            ORDER BY members.firstName ASC";


$danresult = $conn->query($dansql2);

$allAvg = 0;
while($row = $danresult->fetch_assoc()) {
    $allAvg += $row['membersAvg'];
    echo $row['firstName'] . ' ' .$row['lastName'] . ' Avg = ' . $row['membersAvg']; 
}
echo 'Avg of Avgs = ' . $allAvg / $danresult->num_rows;
?>
```

Comment: Where are you getting `$row['membersAvg']` from?

Comment: Look at the query. I did the simple average calc as part of the query

Comment: Hm thats going to interfere with everything else. I will see what I can do with this, cheers for your help.

Comment: If you also meed the individual columns then just include those in the query as well

Comment: `$allAvg = 0` << | >> `$allAvg = 0;` ;-)

Comment: Morning Eagle Eyes. Thanks @Fred-ii-

Comment: Mornin' @RiggsFolly (Tired) eagle eyes. Imagine what I can do when I'm at my best ;-) (welcome).